# Commit failed: .DS_Store ist not under version control

Tags: xcode, svn

xCode is giving me trouble, and i've been unable to help myself so far.

When I commit my project, xCode reports:

> **The working copy "[projectName]" failed to commit files**
>
> svn: Commit failed (details follow);
>
> svn: '/Users/[user dir]/[path to project]/[source dir]/.DS_Store' is not under versioning control.

Funny thing is, I'm not even trying to add or commit the .DS_Store. Anyway, I tried to resolve this error by deleting .DS_Store using finder (very futile, pops up again right after killing it), and the command line (less futile, but still no luck).

Then I followed this advise http://soledadpenades.com/2009/07/02/keeping-ds_store-files-at-bay/ to add .DS_Store to my ignore list, both in the project dir and all subdirectories using

```
    svn propset svn:ignore .DS_Store .
```

However, I will admit, that I did not know exactly what I was doing there. I've been using SVN for a long time on Windows exclusively with the Tortoise UI, and feel an appropriate amount of shame for not owning sufficient svn command line skills.

After the ignore, the error looks like this:

> **The Woking copy "[projectName]" has failed to commit files**
>
> svn: Commit failed (details fllow):
>
> svn: File or directory '.' is out of date; try updating
>
> svn: resource out of date; try updating

I guess that happens if you follow advise from the internet blindly without a sufficient level of understanding (shame on me).

Performing an update, didn't do anything, all files were up to date.

Because I don't want to make things worse than they are right now, I'd humbly ask for some help from you awesome guys and gals.

Thanks,
Chris

**Answer**
Forcing a commit from terminal. After that, using source control in xCode worked fine again.

Comment: "File or directory '.' is out of date; try updating" means (as written) - you have to update working copy before commit (somebody commit to repo and you haven't this revision)

Comment: svn propset svn:ignore (-R on root folder save some time for you doing recursive operation) mark all .DS_Store files inside WC as "not interested" for SVN - status, commit, ..., operations will not show this files at all in filelists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mac OS stores additional information in [.DS_Store](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store). This is why you can't delete the folder: The OS needs it.

What you need is to tell SVN to ignore the folder. That's what you did.

For some reason, editing `svn:ignore` has the side effect that the folder gets "out of sync" (whatever that means).

The solution here is to update the folder: `svn up .` from the terminal. After that, you can commit the new property.

After restarting Xcode, everything should be fine again.

Try to edit the ignore list from inside Xcode next time, it might do the necessary magic for you.